# Why does jslint hightlight ++?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I have the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < json.AnsData.length; i++) {
```

jsLint is telling me:

```
Warning 96  JS Lint: Unexpected '++'.
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: You can just check the box that says `'tolerate ++ and --'` and you won't get errors about that.

Comment: Style note: preincrement ++i is a better natural choice than i++. The convention is just the wrong way around. For JS it probably doesn't matter, but in C/C++ it can matter as theoretically you may need access to both the un-incremented and incremented values with postincrement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.jslint.com/lint.html:

> The ++ (increment) and -- (decrement) operators have been known to contribute to bad code by encouraging excessive trickiness. They are second only to faulty architecture in enabling to viruses and other security menaces. Also, preincrement/postincrement confusion can produce off-by-one errors that are extremely difficult to diagnose. There is a plusplus option that allows the use of these operators.

JSLint is very strict and reflects the views of its author, Douglas Crockford. Crockford is awesome, but he's also very opinionated and some people find his opinions go too far for their tastes. If you find that avoiding `++` isn't something you can get behind, try JSHint instead of JSLint (or set the option in JSLint to tolerate `++`).

Comment: I didn't use jshint. Is that very different?